# Configure/disable request logging in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

Using yesod 1.6.2.1, when creating a new application (regardless of whether using the scaffolding or using the builtin `warp port foundation`), you get request logs like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2023:11:19:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 ...
```

I don't see where/how they're configured. The `Yesod` typeclass comes with a `shouldLogIO` member, but even if that's set to `return False` you still get these messages on each request. While these are mostly harmless, I'd at least like to disable them in tests because the mess up the test runner output.

What actually creates these log entries, and how do I configure/disable them?

Comment: Wasn't sure if I should add this question but at least to me this wasn't obvious and surprisingly I couldn't find a QA on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These logs come from a WAI middleware that the `warp` helper in `yesod` as well as the scaffolding create. There doesn't seem to be a central place to configure this by default, however it can be disabled by simply not including the middleware in question.

In the scaffolded site, this is in the `withApp` function in `TestImport.hs`:

```
withApp :: SpecWith (TestApp App) -> Spec
withApp = before $ do
    settings <- loadYamlSettings
        ["config/test-settings.yml", "config/settings.yml"]
        []
        useEnv
    foundation <- makeFoundation settings
    wipeDB foundation
    logWare <- liftIO $ makeLogWare foundation
    return (foundation, logWare)
```

simply replace `(foundation, logWare)` with `(foundation, id)` here (this works since WAI middlewares are simply functions of type `Application -> Application`).

Similarly, in the scaffolded site, you can just remove `logWare` from `makeApplication` in `Application.hs`:

```
makeApplication :: App -> IO Application
makeApplication foundation = do
    logWare <- makeLogWare foundation
    -- Create the WAI application and apply middlewares
    appPlain <- toWaiAppPlain foundation
    return $ logWare $ defaultMiddlewaresNoLogging appPlain
```

When not using the scaffolded site, to run the application without the default logging middleware just do something similar to the scaffolded site and convert your foundation to a WAI app via [`toWaiAppPlain`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.24.4/docs/Yesod-Core-Dispatch.html#v:toWaiAppPlain), add the default middlwares *without* logging via [`defaultMiddlewaresNoLogging`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.24.4/docs/Yesod-Core-Dispatch.html#v:defaultMiddlewaresNoLogging), and use [`Network.Wai.Handler.Warp.run`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.28/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:run) to run the resulting WAI application with the warp server`.